# Modelling the idea of throwing an exception in a UML Activity Diagram

Tags: exception, uml

The ability to model the idea of catching an exception is pretty easy in a UML activity diagram - but what about THROWING the exception? The closest thing I can seem to find would be the throwing activity sending a signal with a stereotype of `<<exception>>` and then hitting a flow-final node, but I don't know that this is considered best-practice. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[UML 2.4 superstructure specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4/), in chapter 12.3.44 Pin (from BasicActivities, CompleteActivities), on figure 12.122 (page 416), you can see output pin for throwing exceptions. There is also an example on figure 12.129 (page 419).

Answer (score 4):

UML notation exists to show exceptions. 
Look at Larman's book:

> Applying UML and Patterns: An
>   Introduction to Object-Oriented
>   Analysis and Design and Iterative
>   Development, Third Edition By Craig
>   Larman  **35.3. Handling Failure** Chapter

Larman says that :

> *In summary, UML notation exists to
>   show exceptions. **However, it is rarely
>   used.** **This is not a recommendation to
>   avoid early consideration of exception
>   handling.** Quite the opposite: At an
>   architectural level, the basic
>   patterns, policies, and collaborations
>   for exception handling need to be
>   established early, because it is
>   awkward to insert exception handling
>   as an afterthought. However, **the
>   low-level design of handling
>   particular exceptions is felt by many
>   developers to be most appropriately
>   decided during programming or via less
>   detailed design descriptions, rather
>   than via detailed UML diagrams.***

Comment: interesting, but you gave no answer:)

Comment: @ Gabriel Ščerbák The answer is within you, do not search for it elsewhere.:-). It is just a guide. You may extract "concrete" answer from it depends on your context.

Comment: ok:) But you know, the question was "How do I...?" and your answer is basically "Yes and it is important...":).

Comment: @Gabriel Ščerbák The answer is clear. First Part: Look at the book chapter. You can see different ways of showing exceptions in Uml. Second Part:Is it considered as best practice?should we show exception in a Uml diagram? I agree with Larman and so put it an "extract" from his book. Did not read my answer?Short answer is do not use detailed Uml diagrams for exceptions...You can make abstractions Gab...No Need concrete answers.

Comment: now it makes sense - from the extract you cited it wasn't clear if the solution is in the book or not.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the throwing an exception is displayed in the sequence diagram. I would say the following example is mainly used with Java but don't really know if it could also corespond to higher level of abstraction !!

Comment: You can write anything and say you know what it means - it is called no semantics.

Comment: This is totally logical for me in a java development but if your brain is Model driven oriented I mean always generate all the code from the model then good luck !!

Comment: I am not talking about any code generation or model driven stuff. I am saying that you choose incorrect way to depict what you want and assume everybody would understand it correctly. I can explain this in Java if you like:

Comment: Insetead of writing `throw new Exception()` you use your custom method `throwNewException()`.

Comment: The name of the method could be throwNewException or whatever you want. The round black circle is the graphical notation. by the way my example is just what I found on the website !!

Comment: But the question is why to have a method for something, that is part of the language? If you for example rewrote all your code to use 'assign(lhs, rhs)' instead of 'lhs = rhs' wouldn't it be just more confusing? The problem with solutions from web is that many of them are written by lazy people who haven't looked in the UML specification.